# How to access arraydata from jquery post method in another jsp

Tags: java, jquery, post, parameters, request

**jquery :**

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();('#myTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () 
{      var currrowvalue=null;
          //console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
         currrowvalue = table.row(this).data();
            $.post('sample.jsp',{arraydata:currrowvalue}) .done(function()
        {

  location.href='sample.jsp';                 
    });

     //window.open("pasofinoshowentryformtemplate229.jsp");
   });
```

Jsp Page :

```
<%
 str= request.getParameterValues("arraydata[]");
%>   
<input type="text" value="<%=str[0]%>">
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   org.apache.jsp.sample_jsp._jspService(sample_jsp.java:92)

Help me

Comment: try to use request.getParameterValues("arraydata") "arraydata" is the name of your parameter. in your code you have add "[]".

Comment: yes i did try even it raised same exception.please tel me if anyother way of handling